# Why do I need " as_default() " to write instructions in a Tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why can't I just use g1,g2 directly without making it default?

Why do I have to use `with g1.as_default() as g:`

```
g1 = tf.Graph()
g2 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default() as g:
  with g.name_scope( "g1" ) as g1_scope:
    matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
    matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
    product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are in eager mode, every time you create a new operation (more or less any `tf.*` function), a new node is added to a TensorFlow computation graph. If you have not specified otherwise, that graph will be the "default graph", a graph that is created for you by default by TensorFlow (you can renew the default graph with `tf.reset_default_graph()`). However, if you want to keep things tidier, you may want to have some control over which operation goes in which graph. For this you can create your own graphs and use the `as_default()` context. This will make the given graph the default, so every new operation will now be added to that graph instead of the global default. In general, this is the only way to specify where you want to put each operation. This allows you, for example, to keep different models in different graphs, which may make it easier to save and restore, or simply keep isolated (note each session belongs to a single graph, so the computation in one graph cannot possibly affect a different graph).